# calculate total price in rust

Tags: rust, substrate

I have list of struct for store basket of online store :

```
pub struct UserTransationHistory<T: Config> {
    transactionId: <T as frame_system::Config>::Hash,
    items: Vec<UserBasketItemItem<T>>,
    customerPay: bool,
    confirmPay: bool,
    storeOwner: T::AccountId,
    storeId: <T as frame_system::Config>::Hash,
}

pub struct UserBasketItemItem<T: Config> {
    itemId: <T as frame_system::Config>::Hash,
    count: u32,
    price: u32,
}
```

i wanna to calcualte all basket price , i wrote this code :

```
        Baskets::<T>::mutate(storeId, |basket| -> DispatchResult {
            match basket {
                Some(basket) => {
                    let mut total_price = 0;
                    basket.items.iter().map(|x| total_price += x.price).rev();
                    log::info!("**************** Total Price {:?}", total_price);
                    Ok(())
                },
                _ => Err(<Error<T>>::StoreItemNotFound.into()),
            }
        });
```

i aded items on basket with price `10` but every time i log the `total_price` it shows me `0` .

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ? **

```
Baskets::<T>::mutate(storeId, |basket| -> DispatchResult {
                match basket {
                    Some(basket) => {
                        let mut total_price = 0;
                        basket.items.iter().map(|x| total_price += x.price).rev();
                        log::info!("**************** Total Price {:?}", total_price);
                        Ok(())
                    },
                    _ => Err(<Error<T>>::StoreItemNotFound.into()),
                }
            });
```

Comment: `map` is not intended for side effects.  Use `reduce` or `for`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators in rust are [lazy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#laziness). The line `basket.items.iter().map(|x| total_price += x.price).rev()` does nothing, because none "consuming" method was called on the iterator. If you want to add numbers together in an iterator you could use `sum`. So try this:

```rust
let total_price: u32 = basket.items.iter().map(|x| *x.price).sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simplified example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let numbers = [1, 2, 3];

    let mut sum = 0;
    numbers.iter().map(|x| sum += *x).rev();
    println!("{sum}");
}
```

If you compile and run this, you'll get this warning:

```
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
5 |     numbers.iter().map(|x| sum += *x).rev();
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_must_use)]` on by default
  = note: iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed
```

Pay special attention to the line "iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed". Basically, when you create an iterator, you don't actually *do* the iteration. Instead, you create an object that you can iterate over.

If you actually want to run the iterator, you'd have to call `.next()` on it repeatedly, or put it in a `for` loop, etc. But that's probably not what you want:

```rust
let sum: i32 = numbers.iter().sum();
```

Or in your case:

```rust
let total_price: i32 = basket.items.iter().map(|x| x.price).sum();
```

(of course, change `i32` to whatever number type you're using)